# CakePHP 3 use default routing in some cases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.5 website. It was necessary to set slugs without any url prefixes like /pages/slug, so I wrote the following rule:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'redirectPage']
)
->setMethods(['GET', 'POST'])
->setPass(['slug'])
->setPatterns([
    'slug' => '[a-z0-9\-_]+'
]);
```

It works nice, but in some cases I want cakePHP to route as default (Controller/Action/Params). For example, I want /admin/login to call 'login' action in 'AdminController'.
I have two ideas that doesn't need exact routings, but I can't make any of them to work:

1. Filtering some strings by pattern: It would be nice if I could filter some strings, that if slug doesn't match pattern, it will simply skip the routing rule.
2. Create a '/admin/:action' routing rule, but then I cant use :action as an action variable. It causes errors.

   ```
   $routes->connect(
       '/admin/:action',
       ['controller' => 'Admin', 'action' => ':action']
   )
   ```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `prefix` for admin restricted area. 
Example:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

$routes->connect('/:slug' , [
    'controller' => 'Pages', 
    'action' => 'display', 
    'plugin' => NULL
], [
    'slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9/-]+', 
    'pass' => ['slug']
]);
```

Now, for example, path `/admin/dashboard/index` will execute method in `Admin` "subnamespace" `\App\Controller\Admin\DashboardController::index()`

Its nicely described in docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/admin/:action',
    ['controller' => 'Admin'],
    ['action' => '(login|otherAllowedAction|someOtherAllowedAction)']
);
```

Also, your slug routes seems to not catch `/admin/:action` routes, b/c dash is not allowed there: `[a-z0-9\-_]+`